# Map marker styling with image using jvectormap and rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jvectormap

if anyone can help me out, then much appreciated! I am using the jvectormap with Rails 4.1.9 and everything seems to work except rending the custom marker image overlay on top of the map configuring the jvectormap's markerstyle option:

```
$(function() {
  $('#world-map').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    zoomOnScroll: false,

    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        image: 'smarker.png',
        offset: [0,0],
        r: 5
      }
    },

    backgroundColor: '#2A2B2D',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City'}
    ]
});
```

The script is an inline function within the view erb file for now and will refactor later. The image is located in app/assets/images/smarker.png. I just want it to work. It seems to be a asset pipeline problem with the marker image when passing through jvector map function, but I'm just a beginner with Rails and need help on this ...

I have tried using <%= image_tag "smarker.png" %>, but then the whole map disappears... so I am stumped!

Thanks!